# Way to display mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM in datetime-local

Tags: html, angular

My input type="datetime-local"  display in textbox is --->
    mm/dd/yyyy _ *:* _ _ _ .
Now i want it to display ----> mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM or mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm _ _ in the text box . Is there a way to do it.

How to implement it here , i want to display it in a form-->

**transaction.component.html**

```
  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" 
   [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']" 
   [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction"   useValueAsDate>
```

Comment: there are tons of plugins, like https://momentjs.com/. There's also a angular integration, but I'm too lazy to look it up for you.

Comment: Read [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepipe as:

```
<p>The custom date is {{dateValue | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a'}}</p>
```

here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

**Update1:**

as per your requirement you have to do following:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" 
    [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']" 
    [ngModel]="toDateTransaction | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a'" useValueAsDate (ngModelChange)="toDateTransaction=$event">
```

Comment: how to use it here --> <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']" 
                    [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction"   useValueAsDate>

Comment: i want to use it in a form

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava did it help you?

Comment: The server is down..so i haven't tried it yet. I am sure it will work. Thank you

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava Okay, once you check it you can accept the answer. There would be a ✔ at top left of the answer.

Comment: it did not work -->Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 20 in [toDateTransaction| date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a'=$event] in ng:///MasterSystemModule/TransactionComponent.html@46:20 ("orm-control" [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']"

Comment: div class="form-group ">
                  <strong style=" font-size: 13px ;color: #333;">To: </strong>
                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']" 
                  [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a'" useValueAsDate (ngModelChange)="toDateTransaction = $event">
  <div>.  I have even imported--> import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava you have not copied it correctly, note that `[]` for `ngModel`, you are using `[()]`. So your HTML would be
`<div class="form-group "> <strong style=" font-size: 13px ;color: #333;">To: </strong> <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" [formControl]="dateTransactionForm.controls['toDateTransaction']" [ngModel]="toDateTransaction | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a'" useValueAsDate (ngModelChange)="toDateTransaction = $event"> <div>`

Comment: can you try by changing type to `text` rather than `datetime-local`?